# JavaScript isset() function

Tags: javascript, php

How to check `isset` in javascript.

I have used in the following way.

```
var sessionvalue = document.getElementById('sessionvalue').value;

if(Here I have to check if isset the sessionvalue or not){

  if(sessionvalue == "" || sessionvalue == null)
    {
        document.getElementById('sessionvalue').style.borderColor="red";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('sessionvalue').style.borderColor="#ccc";
    }
}
```

Comment: similar but def not a duplicate question.. guy's asking about a variable, the referenced question is asking about array values. This is a good question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When javascript variables are not declared and you try to call them, they return `undefined`, so you can do:

`if (typeof sessionvalue == "undefined" || sessionvalue == null)`

Comment: @user3338098 The question was about if the object exists and not the object's property. Quite obviously, in order for the property of an object to exist, the object must exist first. So here your condition will slightly change. You will check if the object exists first and if it does, go on looking for the property. Refer an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/kx6gcLLm/

Answer (score 16):

You can just do:

```
if(sessionvalue)
```

The above will automatically check for `undefined`, `null` (And `NaN` ,`false`,`""`)

You can even make it a global function if you need it like you're used to in php.

```
function isset(_var){
     return !!_var; // converting to boolean.
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you! Can also check multiple vars like if ( (var1) && (var2) ) {}

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(typeof(data.length) != 'undefined')
    {
       // do something
    }

    if(empty(data))
    {
        // do something
    }

   if(typeof(data) == 'undefined' || data === null)
   {
     //do something
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do `if(sessionvalue)` that's it you don't need anything else and remember you can compare apples with cars in javascript, you can check if value is null or undefined with  `if(sessionvalue)` or `if(!sessionvalue)`, your code will be :

```
document.getElementById('sessionvalue').style.borderColor= sessionvalue ? "red" : "#CCC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Code as below

```
var sessionvalue=document.getElementById('sessionvalue').value;
if(typeof sessionvalue != 'undefined'){

    if(sessionvalue=="" || sessionvalue == null)
    {
        document.getElementById('sessionvalue').style.borderColor="red";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('sessionvalue').style.borderColor="#ccc";


    }
}
```